# Generate hidden form field data with rails button_to helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, helper

Currently, i use the following code for passing params[:id] to line_items create

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', { controller: 'line_items', action: 'create', id: brick },  class: 'green radius nice button', method: :post, remote: true %>
```

However, it will append the id param on url query which i didn't suppose button_to to do. What i want is passing the id param via hidden the form field. Can i do that in button_to or any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 16):

Starting with Rails 4.1.0, [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) has now the additional options **:params** which can receive a hash that will be transformed into hidden fields. For example:

```
button_to 'Send Invitation', invitation_path(user), params: {'user[email]' => user.email}
```

Will give :

```
<form action="/users/invitation" class="button_to" method="post">
   <div>
       <input type="submit" value="Resend">
       <input name="user[email]" type="hidden" value="user@yahoo.com">
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in a module of my project:

First, I added a form with a hidden field:

```
<%= form_tag({:action => 'my_action'}, :id=>"item_form", :method => :post, :remote=>true) do%> 
  <%= hidden_field_tag :item_id, 0%>
<% end %>
```

all mi items on the list will have a check_box_tag wich contains the item id:

```
<%= check_box_tag "item_ids", item.id, false,:id => item.id, :class => "my_fancy_class"%>
```

when an item is picked just catch the event, replace the value on the hidden_field and trigger the form:

```
function( event, ui ) {
        $("#item_id").attr('value',ui.selected.id);
        $('form#item_form').submit();
      }
```

if you want to render stuff just add a action.js.erb file to your controller view folder, but thats another thing.